# HOW to use JSON file in chart js?

Tags: json, django, charts

I want to add data from json file to chart js in (django) but it do not appear 
in our file placed in static folder

```
 <canvas id="canvas" width="80" height="30"></canvas>



 $.getJSON("JSONnigberOfPopulition.json", function (json) {

  var labelsChart = json.map(function(item) {
  return item.AvgTravelTime;
   });
  var dataChart = json.map(function(item) {
 return item.Pop_ofNeigbor_riyadh;
  });
```

Here as you can see this chart part :

```
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   var config = {
 type: 'line',
  data: {
   labels:labelsChart,
  datasets:[{
  label: 'Graph Line',
  data: dataChart,
 backgroundColor:'rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.3)'

   }]
    }
  };

   var myChart = new Chart(ctx,config);
  });
```

Comment: any idea ? i really need it in fast time .

Comment: i think problem on url part so any idea ? pleas pleas i need help ): ):